# Connecting clients with TFS Server in a Workgroup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Let's say, I have 3 PCs connected via LAN(no Active Directory). In every PC, I have 3 users. So I have these users, PC1\UserA, PC2\UserB, PC3\UserC. I have setup the TFS 2010 Server on PC1. Now for making this work in a WorkGroup, I have created two users in PC1(PC1\UserB, PC1\UserC) with same password. For testing purpose, I have given admin rights to both of these users. I have also make the workspace public. When the PC2\UserB try to connect with server with his user/password he can successfully connect. But when a user try to edit a file, he is getting this error.

***The operation cannot be completed because the user .... does not have one or more required permissions (Use) for workspace .....***

The same is happening with PC3\UserC.

Answer (score 2):

Have you given those users Roles or other specific permissions within TFS?  By default the users won't be able to do much without being assigned Roles (like Contributor) that allow them to edit files or tasks.

Comment: From TFS Server Console > Application Tier > Administrator Security > Window User or Group, I have added these users and checked all checkboxes in Allow column. Is there is any other way?

Comment: From inside visual studio, go to team explorer, right click on the project you want to give them access to. Team Project Settings > Group Membership.  Add the user accounts to the groups from there.  That will set their roles on a per project basis.  You can set them on the entire server by following similar steps on the root node (usually tfs).

Comment: I have manage to solve this issue. Thanks. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/8b2955e5-49e2-4d59-9b44-a7af09628243/?prof=required